# Cannot used styled-component in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**Problem:**

In my react-native application, I am using simple-react-chatbot with the styled-component package. This is how my code looks like.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import ChatBot from "react-simple-chatbot";

const theme = {
  background: "#f5f8fb",
  fontFamily: "Helvetica Neue",
  headerBgColor: "#EF6C00",
  headerFontColor: "#fff",
  headerFontSize: "15px",
  botBubbleColor: "#EF6C00",
  botFontColor: "#fff",
  userBubbleColor: "#fff",
  userFontColor: "#4a4a4a"
};

class Trafficbot extends PureComponent {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Trafficbot",
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "#06153b"
    },
    headerTintColor: "#fff",
    headerTitleStyle: {
      color: "#ffff"
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <ChatBot
          headerTitle="Speech Recognition"
          recognitionEnable={true}
          steps={[
            {
              id: "1",
              message: "What is your name?",
              trigger: "2"
            },
            {
              id: "2",
              user: true,
              trigger: "3"
            },
            {
              id: "3",
              message: "Hi {previousValue}, nice to meet you!",
              end: true
            }
          ]}
        />
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default Trafficbot;
```

But when I run the application, It is giving me an error like this.

```
Object(se.keyframes) is not a function. (In 'Object(se.keyframes)(a())','Object(se.keyframes)' is an instance of Object)
```

I look for a solution but I was unable to find any solution. Can someone help me to solve this problem? Thank you!.

Comment: Which version of react and react-native are you using?

Comment: look at your export

Comment: @HardikModha '"react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.2",
    "react-simple-chatbot": "^0.4.2",
    "styled-components": "^4.1.2"'

Comment: @NeelGala It is correct in my code when I copy the code to the stack overflow that was happened. I have edited the question and corrected it. sorry for that.

Comment: You can't use `simple-react-chatbot` in `react-native`

Comment: @PritishVaidya then can you tell me what can i used instead for simple-react-chatbot